# How to accept the arguments from the user when using variable length Arguments in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, user-input

How do I accept variable length arguments for multiplication program, I can pass the parameters with the function name, however, I don't know how to accept the input from the user.

I have used *argvs to accept any number of arguments. I have tried taking value from the user inside the for loop so that n number of arguments can be passed but it is not working. I know the code is not correct but I don't know how to do it.

Here's some code :

```
def mul(*nums):
    result = 1
    for n in nums:
            #nums = int(input("Enter the Numbers to be multiplied : "))
            result *= n
    return result 

#print(mul(4,5,4,4))
 print(mul(nums))
```

Expected - 320

```
Actual - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "args_and_kwargs.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(mul(nums))
NameError: name 'nums' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a list for that

```
def mul(*nums):
    result = 1
    for n in nums:
        result *= n
    return result 

nums = input("Enter the Numbers to be multiplied : ").split(" ")
nums = [int(num) for num in nums]
print(mul(*nums))
```

Comment: I am actually practicing the use of *args & **kwargs. Can you please help me with that in applying in the above example?

Comment: I edited my code, you can just pass your list as *args

Comment: How would I do it for **kwargs :                                                                        
 ```def intro(**kwargs):
  try: 
   if len(kwargs) == 0:
    print("No data available.")
   else:
    for key,value in kwargs.items():
     print("%s : %s" %(key,value))
 
  except IndexError as e:
   print("Index error")

 print("User Info")
 print("---------------------------")
intro(Name = "abc", City = "cad", Profession = "ste")```